# kendo UI Grid 2 Table with Primary & foreign key Relation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, entity-framework-5

I'm using Kendo UI with Entity Framework, First Database approach, I have 2 tables with primary & foreign key relationship .

I can easily populate first table in kendo UI grid with no error, if second table rows is empty.

But as I give record to second table, Kendo UI grid is empty, it don't load the rows of first table.  Kindly help me.